# .preventDefault() no longer functioning as should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have got to be missing something simple. This script was functioning as anticipated until I added a new element to toggle the input box with a button in the nav bar. Now the form will redirect on submission.

The behaviour expected is that when input is submitted it appears as a comment underneath the comment box.

Currently my .preventDefault(); is no longer working on the click as I am being redirected. I have put too many hours into trying to figure out what went wrong and need some insight on what I changed or implemented incorrectly.

```
$(function () {

    //Toggle compose input box
    $(".compose").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".new").slideToggle("slow");
        textarea.focus()
    })

    //compose input to comment
    $('.Form').on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // 1. Grab the content of the form
        let formData = $('.Form').serialize();
        let entry = $('.textarea input').val();

        console.log(entry)
        if (entry === null || entry === '') {
            alert('text too short!')
        } if (entry.length > 140) {
            alert('text too long!')
        } else {
            // 2. Submit using ajax
            $.ajax('/comments', {
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
            }).then(function (success) {

                console.log('succesful')
                // 4. Make sure the new comments shows
                return $.ajax('/comments');
            }).then(renderComments());
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<main class="container">
  <section class="new">

    <form action='/comments' Method='POST' id="Form">
      <h2>Compose Comment</h2>
      <textarea id="textarea" name="text" onfocus='this.select()' placeholder="What are you humming about?"></textarea>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
      <span class="counter">140</span>
    </form>
  </section>
```

Comment: You need to include `event` within the parameters of the callback function of your first `.click()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form has id="Form", but you are selecting class with jQuery.

i.e you need:

```
//compose input to comment
$('#Form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Be careful, serializing logic is using class also, update your references.

Comment: Ahh that you. I got myself mixed up when I grabbed some code from my previous commit. Starting falling down the stack as I tried to figure out the changes that hadn't been made at that point.

Thanks! got it fixed and back on track.

Comment: Glad to hear it, accept the answer please.
Also check your missing event parameter as @GROVER mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Toggle compose input box
$( ".compose" ).click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
$( ".new" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
 textarea.focus()
})
```

You are not passing the 'event' parameter in this binding as shown below in order to get `preventDefault` to function appropriately.

```
//Toggle compose input box
$( ".compose" ).click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$( ".new" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
 textarea.focus()
})
```